# Class not working until composer dump-autoload

Tags: php, laravel

I created folder name - Birds and in this folder i created class Birds.php then add this to composer.json,

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Birds\\": "Birds/",
        }
    },
```

To load i have to run - composer dump-autoload -o and that's fine for first time to take that folder, But then i created new interface class like this :

```
namespace Birds\Validator;


interface BadgeInterface
{
    public function test();
}
```

Interface class not working until in run composer dump-autoload,

My question is why i need to run this every time ? i am using laravel as framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's just how `composer` works. Laravel is just a PHP framework, so it is not able to run `composer` or other tool all the time for you.

If you need to automatically add files all the time, you can just use `cron` or [Laravel's `schedule` command](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling). It will do all the work for you every 5 minutes, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is cause when you create any class composer folder autoload.php can't update . that cause you need to run it manually . it clear you when you install any package at last command there run is composer autoload to update all reference in autoload.php file

Comment: But how is works when create middleware or provider or new model in laravel folder ?

Comment: when you run any laravel command its every command run composer dump-autoload in backend